# Output additional headers in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an more elegant solution to add certain headers to a SQL `SELECT` statement?

For example, I have a dataset with the following:

```
A | B | C | D
=============
Y | 5 | 8 | Z
X | 4 | 8 | Z
```

etc...

In this case, the data isn't too important per se, however I would like to add related headers to the dataset, so the final output to look like:

```
Date Created: 1/1/11
Date Ran: 12/1/11
File Version: 123
A | B | C | D
=============
Y | 5 | 8 | Z
X | 4 | 8 | Z
```

All these will be internal tracking values already in the database, but I'd like to output them all as a single recordset to the final consumer.

I've done something a bit like it with some `UNION ALL`'s but it's far from great.

Comment: SQL is not a presentation layer. You should handle that in your application and not on DB level.

Comment: Don't try to do this in one data set.  Run two SQL queries in a single statement.  `SELECT x FROM y; SELECT a FROM b;` then parse each record one after the other.

Comment: @juergend I totally agree. Sadly the company I'm working for have no presentation layer available at present.

Comment: @RemarkLima - You can use [`PRINT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) like `PRINT('Date Created:  1/1/11')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL Select statement returns rows and columns. It's not designed to format header and footer information, per se, the way you have described your requirement. And, IMO, this shouldn't be the function of a RDMS. Formatting like this should be done on a client or a service that makes a SQL call, not on a SQL Server itself.

Comment: I totally agree, however the company I'm contracted to have no presentation layer at present, and hence the output is direct to Excel - I'd like to it to go as a single dataset so there's no chance of one being updated without the other dataset

Comment: @RemarkLima - Excel ***is*** the presentation layer then.  If you are in an environment where you can't rely on two sequential statements being completed, then that's the problem to concentrate on.  What if someone accidentally deletes some values from Excel?  That's when VBA and passwords come into it.